# Does NextJS have single page application mode?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, single-page-application, server-side-rendering

I have a project using React & NextJS. Currently, I have a custom _app.js that make the page become SSR. But now I want the page not being load on the server-side. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use next.js dynamic import (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import):

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(() => import('../components/hello3'), { ssr: false })
```

You can also write HOC like:

```
import React from 'react';

const isClient = () => typeof window !== 'undefined';

export const withClientRenderOnly = <P extends Record<string, unknown>>(
    WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>
) => {
    const WrappedWithClientRenderOnly: React.FC<P> = props => {
        if (!isClient()) return null;

        return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
    };

    return WrappedWithClientRenderOnly;
};
```

Or create simple composition:

```
const ClientRenderOnly: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
    const [isMounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => setMounted(true), []);

    if(!isMounted) return null;

    return children;
};

const Page = () => <ClientRenderOnly>Page</ClientRenderOnly>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to build SPA with SSR, right?
I'm confused because you said you now don't want server-side rendering.
If you don't want SSR, why are you using NextJs?, cause NextJs is for SSR

One more point is that custom '_app.js' doesn't make it SSR. Here are the features what you can do with custom APP

- Persisting layout between page changes
- Keeping state when navigating pages
- Custom error handling using componentDidCatch
- Inject additional data into pages
- Add global CSS

(https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app)

Answer (score 0):

In nextjs there are 3 types of rendering Server side render, Server side generation and client side rendering. creating an custom _app won't make it SSR. please have a look on there document